# Importing CSV in pandas with $$ as delimiter

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to import a csv in pandas with `$$` as delimiter, I would expect the following command to work:

```
pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter="$$")
```

This however returns the following error:

> Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not
>   support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+'
>   are interpreted as regex), but this causes 'error_bad_lines' to be
>   ignored as it is not supported by the 'python' engine.

Is this operation even possible in Pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape `$` by `\`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep="\$\$", engine='python')
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""a$$b
a$$1
s$$2
f$$3"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep="\$\$", engine='python')
print (df)
   a  b
0  a  1
1  s  2
2  f  3
```

Comment: @Anthon - Thank you. i am curious, how do you create nike sign? What is code?

Comment: @jezrael I am lazy and copy it in from a text with messages. It is Unicode position 0x2417 "Heavy Check Mark".

Comment: @Anthon - Thanks ✔